# Exporting output of custom multiple regressions from R to Latex

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to export the results of multiple regressions in a single table. Ideally, it should be formatted similar to `stargazer()` output. 
The problem is that I have not found reliably working R functions for the kind of regressions I need (Fama-MacBeth regressions), so I use my custom regression functions, which produce all necessary output (estimates of coefficients, standard errors, t-stat, R^2).

Does `stargazer()` or other similar function have the parameters, which allow me to export results of multiple regressions to Latex in a nice form when output of my regression is just a dataframe?

EDIT: I was just wondering whether it is possible to create publication-style tables, looking like this:
[image]

Comment: So what's not working for you? In `stargazer::stargazer(...)` function **`...`** arguments takes model objects and/or data frames, vector, etc. If you can format output of your functions to get data frames or objects of `lm` class `stargazer` should be able to handle that.

Comment: When I use stargazer(output1, output2), I get latex output in the form of two separate tables. I want to get 1 table, in which each column corresponds to different regression specification. Output1 and output2 are two dataframes, which contain the output of two different regression models.

Comment: You can create a stargazer output of any dataframe with `summary=FALSE` switch. If you have two different regression outputs with output1 and output2, you can merge(output1, output2, all.x=T, all.y=T) the two outputs into a single dataframe, and stargaze that. Here is one example solving a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004490/include-vif-information-in-stargazer-output/49014115#49014115

Comment: Stargazer is a bit limited in what it can do beyond standard regression outputs. Nonetheless you can overwrite the default standard errors and coefficients by providing your own standard errors and coefficients as `se` and `coef` parameters into stargazer. You can also insert your own lines into the output as follows: `add.lines = list(c('My custom R2', 0.001, 0.002, 0.003))`. Here's you can find more discussion on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338567/get-coefficients-estimated-by-maximum-likelihood-into-a-stargazer-table

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that might help you forward (example is too long for a comment, so making this an answer):

```
library(stargazer)
library(broom)

## generate dummy data
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(1000)
z <- x^0.5
y <-  x + z + rnorm(1000, sd=.05)
model1 <- lm(y ~ x)
model2 <- lm(y ~ z)

## transform model summaries into dataframes
tidy(model1) -> model1_tidy
tidy(model2) -> model2_tidy

merge(model1_tidy, model2_tidy, by='term', all.x=T, all.y=T)  -> output

stargazer(output, type='latex', summary=FALSE)
```

You will need to figure out the column headers by yourself but I believe you get the idea.

Comment: You can actually just run `broom::tidy(model)`. No need for `summary` call.

Comment: But this only merge the two outputs. Don't creates a stylized table.

Comment: @Ariel SC, late reply but for future reference, you can use stargazer or other tools to create a nice table from the `tidy()` output.

Comment: @OttoKässi Your code doesn't merge correctly. It duplicates the data (**std.error.x**, **std.error.y**, etc.). You may want to have just one variable called **std.error**. Also your code does not provide the outcome that Moysey Abramowitz is looking for. Please revise it!