# Stargazer one line per data set

Tags: r, stargazer

I am running regressions using various subsets of a data set and a number of dependent variables.

An example using `attitude` data:

```
library(stargazer)

#REGRESSIONS USING DATASET 1
linear1.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints, data = attitude) #dependent 1
linear1.2 <- lm(privileges ~ complaints, data = attitude) #dependent 2

#REGRESSIONS USING DATASET 2
linear2.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints, data = attitude[1:15,]) #dependent 1
linear2.2 <- lm(privileges ~ complaints, data = attitude[1:15,]) #dependent 2
```

As you can see, both depdendent variables `rating` and `privileges` are used in regressions for both subsets of the data. Using a standard `stargazer` approach produces the following table:

```
stargazer::stargazer(linear1.1,linear1.2,linear2.1,linear2.2,
                     omit.stat = "all",
                     keep = "complaints")
```

[image: Table 1]

Each column represents one of the regression models. However, I'd like to have each column represent one dependent variable. Each subset of the data should represent one row:

[image: Table 2]

I have produced this table by hand. Does anyone know whether it's possible to achieve this using `stargazer`? I have a lot of regression subsets and dependent variables, so a highly automatic solution is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that be confusing? By first glance, it looks like there are only two models where "complaints Data1" and "complaints Data2" are independent variables in the same model.

Comment: Correct, it's confusing in this example, however, in my application it makes quite a lot of sense and increases readability. Plus I'm planing to further modify the table afterwards to avoid ambiguities. However, I need this as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wonder if this little modification from this ([Exporting output of custom multiple regressions from R to Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650829/exporting-output-of-custom-multiple-regressions-from-r-to-latex)) will suit you

```
library(stargazer)
library(broom)

## generate dummy data
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(1000)
z <- x^0.5
y <-  x + z + rnorm(1000, sd=.05)
model1 <- lm(y ~ x)
model2 <- lm(y ~ z)

## transform model summaries into dataframes
tidy(model1) -> model1_tidy
tidy(model2) -> model2_tidy

output <- rbind(model1_tidy,model2_tidy)
stargazer(output, type='text', summary=FALSE)
```